# My code is returning an optional

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Am getting all this data from core data and it is returning nil here is my code

```
 var user_id:String!
    var customer_name:String!
    var customer_phone:String!
    var resturant_id:String!
    var card_id:String!
    var customer_coordinate:String!
    var customer_address:String!
    var address_id:String!
    var card_idd:String!

    let param: [String : AnyObject] = ["customer_id":user_id!, "customer_name":customer_name!,"customer_phone":customer_phone!,"total": 3223, "delivery_fee": 200, "restaurant_id": 5, "card_id": card_idd!,"customer_address_id": 20,"customer_street_address": customer_address!, "customer_address_coordinates": customer_coordinate!,"OrderDetails": vrt]

    print(param)
```

But param is returning an optional

here is how am getting data from core data

```
func fetchUserCheck(customer_coordinate:String,customer_name:String,customer_address:String,customer_phone:String){
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext
    var users = [User]()
    var fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "User")
    do{
        users = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [User]

        for user in users{
            user.longLat = customer_coordinate
            user.address = customer_address
            user.name = customer_name
            user.phone = customer_phone                
        }            
    }catch{
        print("")
    }        
}
```

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Do you get any kind of error message? Why do you do `catch{print("");}`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. we need some more info from you. you're getting instances of your entity from core data and then updating some of the field values and not saving the changes - is that really your intention? and you say that's how you get, but actually you set. and you haven't been clear about what is optional and what's nil.

Comment: @Thilo I don't get any error message the app just crashes and return an optional value in the console

Comment: @Wain here is my error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
`

Comment: Do you have a line number where that unwrapping took place?

Comment: Yes its on this line `    let param: [String : AnyObject] = ["customer_id":user_id!, "customer_name":customer_name!,"customer_phone":customer_phone!,"total": 3223, "delivery_fee": 200, "restaurant_id": 5, "card_id": card_idd!,"customer_address_id": 20,"customer_street_address": customer_address!, "customer_address_coordinates": customer_coordinate!,"OrderDetails": vrt]`

Comment: `param` is annotated as **non-optional** `[String : AnyObject]`, however any of the parameter values can be `nil` because they are all declared as **implicit unwrapped optional**. What do you expect? Please learn what optionals are and how to handle them.